# How can i convert an html encoded string to a normal string?

Tags: c#, string, windows-phone-7, html-encode

how can i convert an html-encoded string like the one below to a normal string? (it's **Hello World**)

```
mystr="&#72;&#101;&#108;&#108;&#111;&#32;&#87;&#111;&#114;&#108;&#100;";
```

i am using Windows phone sdk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here another way to do it

```
 string  mystr = "&#72;&#101;&#108;&#108;&#111;&#32;&#87;&#111;&#114;&#108;&#100;";
        var arr = mystr.Split(';');
        string newMStr = string.Empty; 
        foreach (var s in arr)
        {
            string newS= s.Remove(0, 2);
           newMStr+= Convert.ToChar(int.Parse(newS));
        }

         //Print  NewMstr
```

Answer (score 3):

HtmlDecode in System.Net

Just give it the string you want to convert

http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/7c5fyk1k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 2):

In .NET 4

```
 System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode(mystr)
```